# Suggested books on the Pharisees, Sadducees, and Zealots

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, books-generally

What solid books there are on the historical and intellectual development of the Pharisees, Sadducees, and Zealots? Especially written from an orthodox perspective? The Intro to the *Schottenstein Talmud* has a great intro, but probably isn't deep enough. Here's what I've found:

- Schiffman, *From Text to Tradition, a History of Judaism in Second Temple and Rabbinic Times: A History of Second Temple and Rabbinic Judaism*. Ktav: Only 10 pages on Pharisees and Sadducees, but looks interesting.
- Wein, *Echoes of Glory Compact Size: The story of the Jews in the classical era 350 BCE-750 CE*. Looks very introductory
- Rubenstein, *Rabbinic Stories*. Unconvincing.

your suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Books in English?

Comment: It's not a whole book but Berel Wein's Echoes of Glory has a good historical breakdown

Comment: Hi @Harel13, yes in English preferably

Comment: Hi @Dov, the book looks very interesting! thanks!